# How to use a foreign database in extbase/fluid

Tags: fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have a simple extbase extension (typo3) with one controller and one model/view. Now i want to "select *" a MSSQL database and output the results in my view. I have not found any reference on how to realize this.

How can i connect to a foreign database from within my extbase/fluid extension and use the data from this database (MSSQL)? How do i execute a query on the "extDB" and how to i print out the result IN my fluid-view.

This is how i integrate the DB (dbal/adodb):

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['dbal']['handlerCfg'] = array(
    'extDB' => array(
        'type' => 'adodb',
        'config' => array(
            'driver' => 'mssql',
            'username' => 'DB_username',
            'password' => 'DB_password',
            'host' => 'DB_host',
            'database' => 'DB_used',
        )
    )
);


$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['dbal']['table2handlerKeys'] = array (
    'VIEW_TABLE1' => 'extDB', 
    'VIEW_TABLE2' => 'extDB',
);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try extension [Database Abstraction Layer (dbal)](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/dbal/Introduction/Index.html).

Comment: i already saw that. but the question is, how can i execute a query on a DB i have connected to via dbal/adodb??

Comment: to be more clear: i have a MSSQL DB on a different server than my T3 instance. I just want to read the data from a view on this MSSQL DB and output it in my extbase extension.

Answer (score 0):

Example use global variable $GLOBALS. This is tested on Typo3 4.x, but with little updates(?) maybe working on Typo 6.2 (eg. remove deprecated t3lib_div, and use GeneralUtility...).

```
class Abstract {

    /**
     * Access to database
     *
     */
    private
        $msdbHost = 'localhost',
        $msdb = 'database-name',
        $msdbUsername = 'xxx',
        $msdbPassword = 'xxx';

    /**
     * Connect to MS database
     *
     */
    public function connectDatabaseMs() {

        $GLOBALS['MS_DB'] = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_DB');
        $GLOBALS['MS_DB']->sql_pconnect($this->msdbHost, $this->msdbUsername, $this->msdbPassword);
        if($GLOBALS['MS_DB']->link) {
            if($GLOBALS['MS_DB']->sql_select_db($this->msdb)) {
                return $GLOBALS['MS_DB'];
            } else {
                t3lib_div::devLog('[tx_rtgms_lib::connectDatabaseUsers] Can not select database "'.$this->msdb.'".', $this->extKey, 3);
            }
        } else {
            t3lib_div::devLog('[tx_rtgms_lib::connectDatabaseUsers] Can not connect to database "'.$this->msdb.'".', $this->extKey, 3);
        }

        $GLOBALS['MS_DB'] = FALSE;
        return FALSE;
    }

    /**
     * Example
     *
     */
    public function getData() {

        $query = 'SELECT ...';
        $res = $GLOBALS['HOSTAFF_DB']->sql_query($query);
        ...
    }
}
```